# How can I ASPX connect to SQL 2008 in another IP via Windows authorization?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

Is it possible to connect to the same database in different windows by IP? I want to connect using Windows authorization, not by username and password.

Configuration for the local connection to my database:

```
<add name="connectionString" connectionString="Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=ViaMura;Data Source=.\SQL2008" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the proper ports are open, yes. The credentials are transmitted via NTLM authentication, I think.

Comment: yes the ports are open. I try like Data Source=192.168.2.5\SQL2008 but not working